# AWS API PHP - Bitnami

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, sdk, bitnami

I can't find the way to get, via the PHP SDK, the password of my new bitnami wordpress instance, created by ec2 runInstances method.

Is there some methods to get the password of wordpress admin? 
I can find it by hands into "Instance Settings => Get System Log".

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get the password via PHP. You password is generated and then stored in the System Log.

[Application Credentials](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/#how-to-find-application-credentials)

Comment: Thank you. I've already read the [Application Credentials](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/#how-to-find-application-credentials). My goal is to create a new instance with Wordpress (then LAMP) and allow the users log in the new WP backend. Maybe... Can I create an AMI with all my preconfigured software, and then create an instance from this AMI?

Comment: Yes. You can configure an EC2 instance with software, setup passwords, just about anything. Then create an AMI. You can then create one or many instances from the AMI.